# Java match String values to enum, have multiple String match possibilities for each enum value

Tags: java

Given this enum:

```
public enum FileTypes {
        FILEA, FILEB, FILEC;
    }
```

Say you want to see if a String value matches one of the 3 enum types, I have this method:

```
public static boolean validFileType(String value) {
    for (FileTypes fileTypes : FileTypes.values()) {
        if (fileTypes.name().equals(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That works fine, now I'd like to change things a bit. Can I add multiple Strings to match for a single enum? Let's say the String value is "FILEA" or "example-file", could I have both of those specified in the enum? I'd like to keep those in the enum rather than have if statements outside the enum performing the mapping.

Hope that makes sense, thanks for any ideas

Comment: Not sure that I get the question. If you were to add example-file to the enum, would that not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add field(s) to your enum and then implement kind of your own `valueOf()` method. Please take a look on article that gives more details: http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-customized-valueof

Answer (score 2):

You could add the valid entries to you enum constructor like this:

```
public enum FileTypes {

    FILEA("example_file"), //2 valid types
    FILEB("example2", "example3"), //3 valid types
    FILEC(); //Only "FILEC" is valid

    FileTypes(String... otherValidEntries) {
        this.validEntries.add(this.toString()); //I assume that the name of the enum is valid
        this.validEntries.addAll(Arrays.asList(otherValidEntries));
    }
    private List<String> validEntries = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static boolean isValidFileType(String value) {
        for (FileTypes fileTypes : FileTypes.values()) {
            if (fileTypes.validEntries.contains(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(FileTypes.isValidFileType("FILEA")); //true
    System.out.println(FileTypes.isValidFileType("FILEB")); //true
    System.out.println(FileTypes.isValidFileType("example2")); //true
    System.out.println(FileTypes.isValidFileType("example3")); //true
    System.out.println(FileTypes.isValidFileType("FILEC")); //true
    System.out.println(FileTypes.isValidFileType("example4")); //false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
Map<String, FileTypes> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("FILEA", FileTypes.FILEA);
map.put("example-file", FileTypes.FILEA);

boolean validFileType(String value) {
  return map.containsKey(value);
}
```

You get the idea... If you want to closely couple valid "values" with their enums, you could create the enum like this:

```
public enum FileTypes {
    FILEA("FILEA", "example-file"), 
    FILEB("FILEB"), 
    FILEC("FILEC");

    private final List<String> values;

    private FileTypes(String... values) {
        this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
    }

    public boolean validFileType(String value) {
        return values.contains(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum FileTypes {
  FILEA(Arrays.asList("fileA", "the first one")),
  FILEB(Arrays.asList("fileB")), 
  FILEC(Arrays.asList("fileC"));

  private final Collection<String> val;

  private FileTypes(Collection<String> val) {
    this.val = val;
  }

  public static FileTypes findByValue(String val) {
    for (FileTypes ft : values()) {
      if (ft.val.contains(val)) {
        return ft;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("There's no such file type identified by " + val);
  }
}
```

`FILEA` can be found either by `fileA` or `the first one`:

```
System.out.println("file a: " + FileTypes.findByValue("fileA"));
System.out.println("file a: " + FileTypes.findByValue("the first one"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to the enum:

```
public enum FileTypes
{
    FILEA("FILEA"), FILEB("FILEB", "file_b"), FILEC("FILEC", "file_c", "File of type C", "C_FILE");

    private String[] aliases;

    private FileTypes(String... aliases){
        this.aliases = aliases;
    }

    public boolean equals(String string){
        for(int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++){
            if(aliases[i].equals(string)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public static boolean validFileType(String value) {
    for (FileTypes fileType : FileTypes.values()) {
        if (fileTypes.equals(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```